# Combinatorial Testing with unbounded parameter values

Tags: testing, automated-tests, combinatorics, pairwise

I have been using some online combinatorial test generation [tools](https://www.pairwise.org/tools.html), especially for parameters with constraints. However, these tools require the parameter values (or their range) to be specified explicitly. What if I don't know the limit of a parameter in advance and use a placeholder instead, i.e., x?

For example, [CTWedge](https://foselab.unibg.it/ctwedge/) generates combinatorial test suits with this syntax:

```
Model Phone
  Parameters:
    emailViewer : Boolean
    textLines:  [ 25 .. 30 ]
    display : {16MC, 8MC, BW}
  Constraints:
    # emailViewer => textLines > 28 #
```

In my case, the parameter values are like this:

```
Model Phone
  Parameters:
    emailViewer : Boolean
    textLines:  [ 1 .. x ] // unbounded values
    param2:  [ 1 .. m ] // unbounded values
    display : {16MC, 8MC, BW}
  Constraints:
    # emailViewer => textLines > 28 #
```

While running this code, the tool gives error. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. See the language's grammar [here](https://github.com/fmselab/ctwedge/blob/master/ctwedge.parent/ctwedge/src/ctwedge/CTWEdge.xtext), relevant excerpt below:

```
Parameter:
    (Bool | Enumerative | Range) ';'?;

Range:
    name=ID ':' '[' begin=PossiblySignedNumber '..' end=PossiblySignedNumber ']' ('step' step=INT)?; //range of value of a constant

PossiblySignedNumber returns EIntegerObject:
    '-'? INT;
```

So it requires a `begin` and an `end`, both of which are explicitly integers (so no "infinity" value).

Comment: apart from this specific tool, do we have other options?